# If I initialize an array of objects and don't set any of the values, what are the default values?

Tags: java, arrays

I know if it was a primitive type array, such as an int, it would be 0s, but as an object, such as a String or a custom-made class, is it still 0? NULL? Or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's always the default value for the element type - `null` for any class types, 0 for numeric types, `'\0'` for `char` and `false` for `boolean`. (`NULL` doesn't exist in Java, and 0 is a meaningless value for a reference. It may be the *physical representation* in memory, but it's not a reference value in itself.)

See [section 15.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) of the JLS for how array creation works, and [section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for more explicit detail on the default values of different types.

Answer (score 6):

Elements of object arrays are initialized to `null`. Simple as pie.

Answer (score 3):

Any reference to an object is initialized to `null`. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you can find how Java initializes its primitive data types (including references to objects).

To recap:

```
Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char        '\u0000'
any object  null
boolean     false
```

Answer (score 0):

To help you a little bit with the principle of default types think about what could be a conclusive default value for an object?

- For **int** any number makes sense, like *0*
- For **boolean** any logical value makes sense, like *false*
- For **char** any symbol makes sense, like *'\0'*
- ...

There exists a **clear range of valid values** for this types (*for example {false, true}*).
So any value can be used as a default value.

For objects there is no clear range of valid values. An object can hold any member variables or provide some methods but there is **no specific "value" for an object**.